# mvc - hide numbers from a credit or debit card

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The problem is the following I have a field where I enter the card number, is stored correctamenta, what happens the following when I show the data shows me the complete numbering of the card which for security reasons should appear so

************ 1234

so I want to know how I can show the text so, to be able to give more security to the site, help

Comment: I don't think you should be storing credit card information in your database at all. Let the payment companies handle that for you.

Comment: @trailmax what happens is that it is a final project and I need to have them stored in order to validate that there is only one and for security reasons

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking or what the issue is.

Comment: @Amy edit the question to see if you understand

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only site.  I don't read Spanish.  https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Amy im sorry, see the question now

Comment: @Frankenstainero if you only need to store them to validate a uniqueness, why do you need to display them? Also, for security reasons I suggest you store only hash of numbers (like SHA256) - you can still validate collision, but you don't store the actual numbers yourself.

Comment: @trailmax but I need to store them full because, if it is another user, try to store the same card, plus you may already have access to it, you can send credit cards the has associated with it, which is part of the account but I want when I I like the things I get out like that ************ 1234

Comment: No, you don't need to store them in full, unencrypted.  More than that, it's a **bad idea™** to store full card numbers without a **very good reason** to do so.  It is sufficient to store a hash and the last four digits (I used to work at a payment processing company)

Comment: then what do you recommend @Amy

Comment: I just told you.  Store a hash and the last four.

Comment: i dont understand how to do, i am new in this @Amy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to give a high-level overview of how to proceed.  You'll need to make some guided decisions, and will probably need to do some Googling to fill in details.

First, why store a hash instead of the full number?  This should be obvious, but what happens if your database is compromised?  The hacker now has all of your customers card numbers.  That's **very bad**.  So we store a hash instead, wherever possible.  If you *absolutely must* store the full number, you can do so, but you need a solid reason.

1) Choose a hash - [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) is good for our purposes.  For your class assignment, almost any hashing function will do; however, for businesses, [you will want to be PCI-compliant, meaning your hashing function should be cryptographic and salted](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/63272).  That is beyond the scope of your question.  I suggest you go with SHA-1.

2) Modify your database table so it has two columns for the card number information: the SHA-1 hash in hexadecimal format is 40 characters in length.  The last four is, well, four characters long.  So you'll need two columns, of 40 and 4 characters, respectfully.

3) When storing a card into the database, hash it, and also get the last four digits before storing.

```
public static string SHA1HashStringForUTF8String(string s)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

    var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
    byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(bytes);

    return HexStringFromBytes(hashBytes);
}

public static string HexStringFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        var hex = b.ToString("x2");
        sb.Append(hex);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

5) When displaying the redacted card number, just show a bunch of asterisks followed by the last four digits.

6) If you want to check to see if a card number has been previously entered, hash your new card number, then compare that hash to the numbers in the database.  If the hashes are equal and the last four digits are equal, you have a match.